# How to align different components Latex?

Tags: alignment

I would like to align some different components in Latex.

Here you are my code:

```
\documentclass[10pt,english, openany]{book}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix, calc}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{bm}
\usepackage{mathtools}

%KARNAUGH MAP COMMANDS ---------------------------------------------------------

%isolated term
%#1 - Optional. Space between node and grouping line. Default=0
%#2 - node
%#3 - filling color
\newcommand{\implicantsol}[3][0]{
    \draw[rounded corners=3pt, fill=#3, opacity=0.3] ($(#2.north west)+(135:#1)$) rectangle ($(#2.south east)+(-45:#1)$);
    }


%internal group
%#1 - Optional. Space between node and grouping line. Default=0
%#2 - top left node
%#3 - bottom right node
%#4 - filling color
\newcommand{\implicant}[4][0]{
    \draw[rounded corners=3pt, fill=#4, opacity=0.3] ($(#2.north west)+(135:#1)$) rectangle ($(#3.south east)+(-45:#1)$);
    }

%group lateral borders
%#1 - Optional. Space between node and grouping line. Default=0
%#2 - top left node
%#3 - bottom right node
%#4 - filling color
\newcommand{\implicantcostats}[4][0]{
    \draw[rounded corners=3pt, fill=#4, opacity=0.3] ($(rf.east |- #2.north)+(90:#1)$)-| ($(#2.east)+(0:#1)$) |- ($(rf.east |- #3.south)+(-90:#1)$);
    \draw[rounded corners=3pt, fill=#4, opacity=0.3] ($(cf.west |- #2.north)+(90:#1)$) -| ($(#3.west)+(180:#1)$) |- ($(cf.west |- #3.south)+(-90:#1)$);
}

%group top-bottom borders
%#1 - Optional. Space between node and grouping line. Default=0
%#2 - top left node
%#3 - bottom right node
%#4 - filling color
\newcommand{\implicantdaltbaix}[4][0]{
    \draw[rounded corners=3pt, fill=#4, opacity=0.3] ($(cf.south -| #2.west)+(180:#1)$) |- ($(#2.south)+(-90:#1)$) -| ($(cf.south -| #3.east)+(0:#1)$);
    \draw[rounded corners=3pt, fill=#4, opacity=0.3] ($(rf.north -| #2.west)+(180:#1)$) |- ($(#3.north)+(90:#1)$) -| ($(rf.north -| #3.east)+(0:#1)$);
}

%group corners
%#1 - Optional. Space between node and grouping line. Default=0
%#2 - filling color
\newcommand{\implicantcantons}[2][0]{
    \draw[rounded corners=3pt, opacity=.3] ($(rf.east |- 0.south)+(-90:#1)$) -| ($(0.east |- cf.south)+(0:#1)$);
    \draw[rounded corners=3pt, opacity=.3] ($(rf.east |- 8.north)+(90:#1)$) -| ($(8.east |- rf.north)+(0:#1)$);
    \draw[rounded corners=3pt, opacity=.3] ($(cf.west |- 2.south)+(-90:#1)$) -| ($(2.west |- cf.south)+(180:#1)$);
    \draw[rounded corners=3pt, opacity=.3] ($(cf.west |- 10.north)+(90:#1)$) -| ($(10.west |- rf.north)+(180:#1)$);
    \fill[rounded corners=3pt, fill=#2, opacity=.3] ($(rf.east |- 0.south)+(-90:#1)$) -|  ($(0.east |- cf.south)+(0:#1)$) [sharp corners] ($(rf.east |- 0.south)+(-90:#1)$) |-  ($(0.east |- cf.south)+(0:#1)$) ;
    \fill[rounded corners=3pt, fill=#2, opacity=.3] ($(rf.east |- 8.north)+(90:#1)$) -| ($(8.east |- rf.north)+(0:#1)$) [sharp corners] ($(rf.east |- 8.north)+(90:#1)$) |- ($(8.east |- rf.north)+(0:#1)$) ;
    \fill[rounded corners=3pt, fill=#2, opacity=.3] ($(cf.west |- 2.south)+(-90:#1)$) -| ($(2.west |- cf.south)+(180:#1)$) [sharp corners]($(cf.west |- 2.south)+(-90:#1)$) |- ($(2.west |- cf.south)+(180:#1)$) ;
    \fill[rounded corners=3pt, fill=#2, opacity=.3] ($(cf.west |- 10.north)+(90:#1)$) -| ($(10.west |- rf.north)+(180:#1)$) [sharp corners] ($(cf.west |- 10.north)+(90:#1)$) |- ($(10.west |- rf.north)+(180:#1)$) ;
}

%Empty Karnaugh map 4x4
\newenvironment{Karnaugh}%
{
\begin{tikzpicture}[baseline=(current bounding box.north),scale=0.8]
\draw (0,0) grid (4,4);
\draw (0,4) -- node [pos=0.7,above right,anchor=south west] {xy} node [pos=0.7,below left,anchor=north east] {zw} ++(135:1);
%
\matrix (mapa) [matrix of nodes,
        column sep={0.8cm,between origins},
        row sep={0.8cm,between origins},
        every node/.style={minimum size=0.3mm},
        anchor=8.center,
        ampersand replacement=\&] at (0.5,0.5)
{
                       \& |(c00)| 00         \& |(c01)| 01         \& |(c11)| 11         \& |(c10)| 10         \& |(cf)| \phantom{00} \\
|(r00)| 00             \& |(0)|  \phantom{0} \& |(1)|  \phantom{0} \& |(3)|  \phantom{0} \& |(2)|  \phantom{0} \&                     \\
|(r01)| 01             \& |(4)|  \phantom{0} \& |(5)|  \phantom{0} \& |(7)|  \phantom{0} \& |(6)|  \phantom{0} \&                     \\
|(r11)| 11             \& |(12)| \phantom{0} \& |(13)| \phantom{0} \& |(15)| \phantom{0} \& |(14)| \phantom{0} \&                     \\
|(r10)| 10             \& |(8)|  \phantom{0} \& |(9)|  \phantom{0} \& |(11)| \phantom{0} \& |(10)| \phantom{0} \&                     \\
|(rf) | \phantom{00}   \&                    \&                    \&                    \&                    \&                     \\
};
}%
{
\end{tikzpicture}
}

%Defines 8 or 16 values (0,1,X)
\newcommand{\contingut}[1]{%
\foreach \x [count=\xi from 0]  in {#1}
     \path (\xi) node {\x};
}

%Places 1 in listed positions
\newcommand{\minterms}[1]{%
    \foreach \x in {#1}
        \path (\x) node {1};
}

%Places 0 in listed positions
\newcommand{\maxterms}[1]{%
    \foreach \x in {#1}
        \path (\x) node {0};
}

%Places X in listed positions
\newcommand{\indeterminats}[1]{%
    \foreach \x in {#1}
        \path (\x) node {X};
}

\begin{document}

\begin{multicols}{2}

    \begin{Karnaugh}
       \contingut{1,0,0,1,0,1,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,1,1}
       \implicantsol{3}{green}
       \implicantsol{5}{blue}
       \implicant[3pt]{15}{14}{yellow}  
       \implicantdaltbaix[3pt]{0}{8}{red}
    \end{Karnaugh}

\begin{flalign*}
&1. (\bar{x}\bar{y}\bar{z}\bar{w}) + (\bar{x}\bar{y}z\bar{w}) = \bar{x}\bar{y}\bar{w}\\
&2. (xyzw) + (x\bar{y}zw) = xzw\\
&3. xy\bar{z}\bar{w}\\
&4. \bar{x}y\bar{z}w\\
\end{flalign*}

\columnbreak


\begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|}
    \hline
    $ \bm{m_n} $ & $ \bm{x} $ & $ \bm{y} $ & $ \bm{z} $ & $ \bm{w} $ &  & $ \bm{f(x,y,z,w)} $\\ 
    \hline
    $m_0$ & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & $\bar{x}\bar{y}\bar{z}\bar{w}$ & 1\\
    \hline
    $m_2$ & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & $\bar{x}\bar{y}z\bar{w}$ & 1\\
    \hline
    $m_5$ & 0 & 1 & 0 & 1 & $\bar{x}y\bar{z}w$ & 1\\
    \hline
    $m_{11}$ & 1 & 0 & 1 & 1 & $x\bar{y}zw$ & 1\\
    \hline
    $m_{12}$ & 1 & 1 & 0 & 0 & $xy\bar{z}\bar{w}$ & 1\\
    \hline
    $m_{15}$ & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & $ xyzw $ & 1\\
    \hline

\end{tabular}
\end{multicols}
\end{document}
```

[image]

As you can see, using the environment `multicols` there is no alignment between the map, the table and the text below. Is there a way to fix it? Thank you in advance,

Comment: Exactly what kind of alignments do you seek, in terms of vertical and horizontal?

Comment: Why not use two minipages?

Comment: @StevenB.Segletes Both horizontal and vertical, in order to make it better

Comment: @leandriis i don't know what you are referring to, could you please send some examples?